# Stripping filename from HTML Encoded UNIX Path

Tags: javascript, html, unix, encoding

I am writing a NodeJS application using Express and Google Datastore. I am trying to get the filename from a UNIX path. The path is stored in an HTML encoded format in the database.

Here's the path un-encoded:

```
/toplevel/example/text123.txt
```

Here's how the path is stored in the database HTML encoded format:

```
&#x2F;toplevel&#x2F;example&#x2F;test123.txt
```

Since the path is HTML encoded, this line is not working.

```
let filename_only = requested_filepath_unescaped.split('/').pop().toString();
```

I also tried splitting by the encoded characters but that does not work either (perhaps because split doesn't work with multiple characters?)

```
let filename_only = requested_filepath_unescaped.split('&#x2F').pop().toString();
```

What is the best way to either split the string as-is, or de-code the HTML back into an unencoded string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, split works with multiple characters, so I don't know what goes wrong when you tried it.

However if you can use jQuery, you can also decode the html like this:

```
var htmlDecoded = $('<div />').html(htmlEncoded).text()
```

After that you can split on '/'.

(The code I gave creates a div tag in memory (it is not added to the DOM, the web page), after that it sets the html of it, which automatically decodes the html entities.

EDIT:
As I am unsure what the problem of the OP is and I can't comment due to low reputation, I give some more suggestions here.

Maybe the variable you call split on is not really a string object. Try converting to string first:

```
var filename = filepath.toString().split('&#x2F;');
```

Other option is to use regex, but I don't know what exactly solves that, but might be worth trying.

```
var filename = filepath.toString().split(/&#2F;/);
```

EDIT2: Tested and working in Chrome v62 and Node v6.11.4.

Comment: Hmm interesting I wonder why it isn't working when I try it like this split('&#x2F'). I will keep exploring that option. Also I should have clarified, I'm using NodeJS in the back-end so JQuery isn't relevant in this scenario. Thanks!

Comment: Converting to a string first worked, thank you for pointing me in the right direction!